# Passing js object data to flask from react js

Tags: python, reactjs, json, flask

I want to pass an array of JSON object to flask.
My data looks like :

```
{
    "business_code": "U001",
    "cust_number": 200769623,
    "clear_date": "2020-02-11",
    "buisness_year": "2020-01-01",
    "doc_id": "1930438491",
    "posting_date": "2020-01-26",
    "document_create_date": "2020-01-25",
    "document_create_date1": "2020-01-26",
    "due_in_date": "2020-02-10",
    "invoice_currency": "USD",
    "document_type": "RV",
    "posting_id": 1,
    "area_business": "",
    "total_open_amount": 54273.28,
    "baseline_create_date": "2020-01-26",
    "cust_payment_terms": "NAH4",
    "invoice_id": 1930438491,
    "isOpen": 0,
    "aging_bucket": null,
    "is_deleted": 0
  }
```

I tried it by passing the values in URL by modifying the flask code but my company doesn't want flask code to be modified.

I want to pass the data to this and then in return want to receive the response back to my react js application.
My flask code looks like :

```
@app.route("/get_prediction", methods=["GET",'POST'])
def get_prediction():    
    if request.method == "POST":
        doc_id_list = list(request.json["data"])
        print(doc_id_list)
        response = make_response(jsonify(New_Bucket.doc_id_bucket(doc_id_list)),200)
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]="*"
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return response
```

I don't really get how I can accomplish this.

Comment: Use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make the **POST** request. Refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) for more info.